# How do I find out if an old bank account still exists and if I still have funds available in that account?

Tags: united-states, banking, savings

I have an old savings account from old Shawnee Bank in Shawnee Kansas. It shows a balance in it from 1970. How do I find out if it still exists?

Answer (score 1):

Every US state has an website that you can lookup unclaimed property. The bank eventually determined that the account was abandoned and turned the funds over to the state. The Kansas state treasurer website appears to be: https://www.kansasstatetreasurer.com/up_search.php

If they have a record of it, and you can prove ownership you should be able to get the funds at no cost.

If Kansas doesn't have a record of it check neighboring states in case the official HQ of the bank was one state over. It is also possible that the HQ moved if the bank was bought or there was a merger.